# How to resolved http and Site Behavior: Navigation error in android app?

Tags: android, admob, androidhttpclient

Recently I updated android 9 to android 10 but unfortunately, the app sometimes crashes and gives this error.

```
com.fgapps.maker E/chromium: [ERROR:cookie_manager.cc(137)] Strict Secure Cookie policy does not 
allow setting a secure cookie for http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/ for apps targeting >= R. 
Please either use the 'https:' scheme for this URL or omit the 'Secure' directive in the cookie value.
```

I tried using this in manifiest

```
   <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ....>

    <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />
```

I also added build-gradle (app)

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    ...}
```

and also AdMob rejects my app due to **`Site Behavior: Navigation`** violation even I checked all links working properly, so How to resolve this issue. thanks

Comment: Have you found solution?

Comment: Not exactly where the issue. but my issue is resolved by doing this.
1- remove all ad from back button.
2- remove all ad from mainActivity.
3- remove overlapping if you found.
then request for review.

Comment: Thank you for response, i also removed ad from back pressed and from the activity which  contains button to open another app. Now issue is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three of my friends resolved errors by following these steps.

1. Just request to google this is an error sometimes google fixes this
   issue without changes in the app.
2. If not fix from step-1 then it maybe needs to remove ads from MainActivity, especially Interstitial ad.
3. and also check the app for unlink remote resources.

Comment: I have made changes to my application many times, every review request has been negative. 5 maybe 6 times. Each time I took something out of the app. None of them worked. Finally, I desperately asked for a re-inspection without a new update and was told there was no problem. It's funny, but I feel like crying.

Comment: @MahmutK. request to admob after a month (31 days), issue will automatically fix

Comment: @Attaullah can you please tell me how to request google as you mentioned in your 1st step. From last few days I am facing this issue and tried everything but still getting same violation. The app request URL link (start with http:// not https://) it's affect to ads?

Comment: @hardkgosai http and https no an issue you can resolve your issue by doing this. 1- remove all ad from back button. 2- remove all ad from mainActivity. 3- remove overlapping if you found. then request for review.

Comment: @Attaullah I already tried your suggested solutions but still same violation.

Comment: @hardkgosai, now you have 2 ways one, remove ads from the main activity or wait for 30 days and request again without any changes. Your request will be accepted without any issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue. my banner ads cover or overlap the contents of the app. After fixing the banner ads published my app again and issue resolved. So in my opinion check your banner ads and also check any direct link that leads to another app or webpage.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue on April 2023, in my case on a Android App.

To fix it, I removed all code Related Interstitial Ads, an removed all code related Banner Ads. Yes, I just remove everything related Interstitial and Banners Ads, and well problem solved.

I keep only the Rewarded videos Ads.