# Strict Secure Cookie policy error in AdMob after updating to Android 11

Tags: android, admob, android-11

After updating my app to compile with API level 30 (Android R, 11), I can't see AdMob test ads, and I'm receiving this error in the log:

> Strict Secure Cookie policy does not allow setting a secure cookie for
> http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/ for apps targeting >= R. Please
> either use the 'https:' scheme for this URL or omit the 'Secure'
> directive in the cookie value.

I'm using the last AdMob version, and I don't have "org.apache.http.legacy" references in Gradle or manifest.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue in Flutter app, after upgrading to latest version of Google's new admob_flutter library: https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter

Comment: Do you have the same problem wither Futter 2.2 ?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

This might come from the webview [`cookie_manager.cc`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/android_webview/browser/cookie_manager.cc).

Also this: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032

Same question here: [How to resolved http and Site Behavior: Navigation error in android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63111960/how-to-resolved-http-and-site-behavior-navigation-error-in-android-app)

It might be temporarily broken, unless they'd set the cookie as expected.

Comment: so it's safe to publish the app with this?

Comment: One probably just needs a version of AdMob, which instead uses a HTTPS URL... and it's about as safe, as the secure cookie not being set through HTTP (which may circumvent the whole idea) - but it is as unsafe as, the URL being plain-text HTTP. It's a lock-out scenario, until the URL would feature a "s".

Answer (score 2):

I'm using flutter and I'm facing the same issue while implementing banner test ads.
Just add the below in android manifest file under application:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

and issue will be resolved.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found how to fix this error, this is not caused due to error in your code don't worry, the error is there in your admob account just go to your payments in admob and just verify your identity this fill fix your problem!