# Strict Secure Cookie policy issue in Flutter app (Android) with AdMob

Tags: android, flutter, admob

I have a Flutter app that shows ads.

I recently changed the **Ad Content Rating** for my app in Admob from *MA* to *G* because my app was directed for families.

After that moment, a test banner ad was loaded, my emulator would shut down with the below error log (this seems to work fine in the test device but every time it crashes the emulator):

```
D/EGL_emulation( 4807): eglCreateContext: 0xec6f6250: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation( 4807): eglMakeCurrent: 0xec6f6250: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb09f9410) (first time)
D/zzez    ( 4807): File /data/user/0/app.wesay.joinedwords/cache/1598581401714.dex not found. No need for deletion
E/chromium( 4807): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(549)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
I/DynamiteModule( 4807): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:21400
I/DynamiteModule( 4807): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 21400
V/DynamiteModule( 4807): Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
I/Ads     ( 4807): This request is sent from a test device.
I/VideoCapabilities( 4807): Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
W/cr_MediaCodecUtil( 4807): HW encoder for video/avc is not available on this device.
D/EGL_emulation( 4807): eglCreateContext: 0xec6f7590: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2
W/Ads     ( 4807): Not retrying to fetch app settings
2
E/chromium( 4807): **[ERROR:cookie_manager.cc(137)] Strict Secure Cookie policy does not allow setting a secure cookie for http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/ for apps targeting >= R. Please either use the 'https:' scheme for this URL or omit the 'Secure' directive in the cookie value.
W/Ads     ( 4807): GET LOCATION COMPILED**
W/say.joinedword( 4807): Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioTrack;->getLatency()I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/ExoPlayerImpl( 4807): Init ExoPlayerLib/2.4.2 [generic_x86_arm, sdk_gphone_x86_arm, Google, 30]
I/flutter ( 4807): BannerAd event is MobileAdEvent.loaded
I/flutter ( 4807): BannerAd event is MobileAdEvent.impression
D/MetadataUtil( 4807): Skipped unknown metadata entry: gsst
D/MetadataUtil( 4807): Skipped unknown metadata entry: gstd
D/CCodec  ( 4807): allocate(c2.android.aac.decoder)
I/Codec2Client( 4807): Available Codec2 services: "software"
I/CCodec  ( 4807): Created component [c2.android.aac.decoder]
D/CCodecConfig( 4807): read media type: audio/mp4a-latm
D/ReflectedParamUpdater( 4807): extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.max-count.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater( 4807): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.subscribed-indices.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater( 4807): extent() != 1 for single value type: input.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater( 4807): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater( 4807): extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater( 4807): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.pool-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater( 4807): extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.pool-ids.values
I/CCodecConfig( 4807): query failed after returning 19 values (BAD_INDEX)
```

The main issue seems to be the quoted part below. I tried the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64605612/strict-secure-cookie-policy-error-in-admob-after-updating-to-android-11) but none of them seem to be relevant to this case.

> [ERROR:cookie_manager.cc(137)] Strict Secure Cookie policy does not
> allow setting a secure cookie for http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/
> for apps targeting >= R. Please either use the 'https:' scheme for
> this URL or omit the 'Secure' directive in the cookie value. W/Ads (
> 4807): GET LOCATION COMPILED

Before resubmitting to Google Play, I want to make sure that I know the reason for this happening as I don't want it to crash on some other device.

Comment: Issue on GitHub : https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/158

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using google_mobile_ads 2.3.0 and the error doesn't seem to occur. The banner ad appears in the Flutter app running on the emulator. Try upgrading to the latest version of [google_mobile_ads](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads) plugin and see if it solves the issue.