# E/chromium: [ERROR:cookie_manager.cc(137)] Strict Secure Cookie policy does not allow setting a secure cookie

Tags: android-studio, webview, admob, chromium

I wanted to test my app on emulator before I publish it in google play store. App works but the ads are not showing. In logcat I have information:

```
E/FA: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled.
E/chromium: [ERROR:cookie_manager.cc(137)] Strict Secure Cookie policy does not allow setting a secure cookie for http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/ for apps targeting >= R. Please either use the 'https:' scheme for this URL or omit the 'Secure' directive in the cookie value.
```

PS

I use webview and svg files in my app

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I don't use any webview, but still get this information while try to setup the admob ads.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strict Secure Cookie policy error in Admob after updating to Android 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64605612/strict-secure-cookie-policy-error-in-admob-after-updating-to-android-11)